# MySQL Join chose only 1 condition from a series of conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a customer table and a separate table that stores addresses for customers.  They often have at least two joined records in the address table, if not more.  When I want a mailing list, I want the billing address for the customer, which is marked by a 'type' column in the address table.  Unfortunately, not every customer has an address marked 'billing'.  How can I write a statement that says to pick the address marked billing, unless there isn't one, in which case choose another.  I don't want to just use 'or' because I only want one record to be chosen.

For simplicity sake, the tables could look like this:

> Customer:
>   id
>
> Address:
>   id
>   custid
>   type (shipping, billing, '', etc)

And here's some sql that isn't what i want (lol):
Select * from Customer inner join Address on address.custid = Customer.id where Address.type = 'billing'

**!!Late Addition!!**
Kevin provided the coalesce solution, which I like very much, but it is only working for a single column from the address table.  I need all the fields/columns from the table to form a useable address.

I've been trying to do it like so (only using two fields here for simplicity):
`select coalesce(concat_ws(',',a1.address, a1.city), concat_ws(',',a2.address, a2.city), concat_ws(',',a3.address, a3.city)) from customer c ...`
however, the concat_ws breaks the coalesce by always returning non-null.
I also tried just doing coalesce independently on each field:
 `coalesce(a1.address, a2.address), coalesce(a1.address2, a2.address2), etc`
but this has the effect of 'mixing up' addresses from 3 different records if for example address2 (for apartment number or whatever) is null for a row, then it will insert a different record's address2 in there.

Does anyone know how to prevent concat_ws from returning non-null even though the fields are null inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the billing address if it exists, otherwise the shipping address:

```
select ifnull(a1.address, a2.address) from customer c
left join address a1 on c.id = a1.custid and a1.type = 'billing'
left join address a2 on c.id = a2.custid and a2.type = 'shipping'
```

if you wanted to check for other types, you could add joins and use coalesce instead of ifnull, like so:

```
select coalesce(a1.address, a2.address, a3.address) from customer c
left join address a1 on c.id = a1.custid and a1.type = 'billing'
left join address a2 on c.id = a2.custid and a2.type = 'shipping'
left join address a3 on c.id = a3.custid and a3.type = 'X'
```

Comment: one more join to include `' '` type condition?

Comment: Every answer listed is fantastic, but I think this is my favorite answer mostly due to not using a union (which I also hadn't thought of). I've never seen the coalesce function before.  I'm going to try it out and if it works I'll come back and give you the check.  Thanks so much to everybody for your excellent input - Kevin, VKP, shawnt00, Ben Kulka.

Comment: @Kevin  Okay, the coalesce solution worked great if I only want a single field from the address table.  However, I need them all.  Care to try to expand on this?  I've been trying to do it like so (only using two fields here for simplicity):
`select coalesce(concat_ws(',',a1.address, a1.city), concat_ws(',',a2.address, a2.city), concat_ws(',',a3.address, a3.city) from customer c ...`  however, the concat_ws breaks the coalesce by always returning non-null.

Comment: `coalesce` like columns and then `concat` afterward: `concat_ws(coalesce(a1.address, a2.address, a3.address), coalesce(a1.city, a2.city, a3.city), ...)`

Comment: @shawnt00 but that has the problem I describe in the question -  "this has the effect of 'mixing up' addresses from 3 different records if for example address2 (for apartment number or whatever) is null for a row, then it will insert a different record's address2 in there."

Comment: Yes, that's true when the columns are nullable and one reason this approach isn't always so great. Instead of coalesce try `case when a1.custid is not null then a1.address when a2.custid is not null then a2.address else '' end`

Comment: @shawnt00 oh... I'll just make each column not allow null and that should make it easier again.

Answer (score 2):

```
select c.id, a.id
from customer c join address a on a.custid = c.id
where a.type = 'Billing'
union
select c.id, a.id
from customer c join address a on a.custid = c.id
where a.type <> 'Billing' 
and c.id not in (select custid from address a where a.type = 'Billing')
```

This is one way to do it.

Comment: add one more condition to the second query `where c.id not in (select custid from address where type = 'Billing')`

Comment: Second half of the union could still return multiple addresses per customer.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be difficult to do this without an OR clause. Assuming you're looking for the address id:

```
SELECT
Address.id
FROM Address LEFT JOIN Customer ON Customer.id = Address.custid
WHERE Address.id EXIST (
    SELECT
    Address.id
    FROM Address LEFT JOIN Customer ON Customer.id = Address.custid
    WHERE Address.type LIKE 'shipping'
) OR Address.type = 'billing'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ...
from customer c join address a on a.custid = c.id
where a.type = 'Shipping'
union all
select ...
from customer c join address a on a.custid = c.id
where a.type = 'Billing' and not exists (
    select 1 from address a2
    where a2.custid = a.custid and a2.type = 'Shipping'
)
```

If you need it a little more generic then you might find this "hack" useful:

```
select * from address
where id in (
    select
        min(case type
            when 'Shipping' then 100000000
            when 'Billing'  then 200000000
            when ...        then 300000000
            else 900000000
        end + a.id) % 100000000 /* not sure of MySQL for modulo operation */
    from address a
    group by custid
)
```